# JPA/Hibernate set is empty although there are values in the db

Tags: hibernate, jpa

i use Hibernate 6.2.7.Final.

Here is my child mapping

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "rule", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "ruleset_id", "value", "result" }))
public class Rule implements java.io.Serializable {



    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ruleset_id", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "id")
    public Ruleset getRuleset() {
        return this.ruleset;
    }
```

and here my parent mapping

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ruleset")
@NamedQuery(name = "Ruleset_by_Species", query = "from Ruleset ruleset join fetch ruleset.rules where ruleset.species.name = :name")
public class Ruleset implements java.io.Serializable {

    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "ruleset", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
//  @JoinColumn(name = "ruleset_id")
//  @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetClass = Rule.class)
//  @CollectionTable(name = "rule", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="ruleset_id"))
    public Set<Rule> getRules() {
        if (rules == null) {
            rules = new HashSet<Rule>();

        }
```

I see that the SQL Statement reads the eager values joined
but the Set keeps empty.
I see that the collection assembly is done - but i get an empty set:

```
[2023-08-09 10:19:41] [DEBUG] [18014] [org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.StandardRowReader.readRow(StandardRowReader.java:93)]: Calling top-level assembler (0 / 1) : org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.collection.internal.EagerCollectionAssembler@c8531b9 
[2023-08-09 10:19:41] [TRACE] [18014] [org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.StandardRowReader.afterRow(StandardRowReader.java:103)]: StandardRowReader#afterRow 
[2023-08-09 10:19:41] [TRACE] [18014] [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.JdbcExtractingLogging.logExtracted(JdbcExtractingLogging.java:28)]: extracted value ([1] : [SMALLINT]) - [12] 
[2023-08-09 10:19:41] [TRACE] [18014] [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.JdbcExtractingLogging.logExtracted(JdbcExtractingLogging.java:28)]: extracted value ([2] : [INTEGER]) - [10416] 
[2023-08-09 10:19:41] [TRACE] [18014] [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.JdbcExtractingLogging.logNullExtracted(JdbcExtractingLogging.java:39)]: extracted value ([3] : [SMALLINT]) - [null] 
[2023-08-09 10:19:41] [TRACE] [18014] [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.JdbcExtractingLogging.logExtracted(JdbcExtractingLogging.java:28)]: extracted value ([4] : [VARCHAR]) - [#2533] 
[2023-08-09 10:19:41] [TRACE] [18014] [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.JdbcExtractingLogging.logExtracted(JdbcExtractingLogging.java:28)]: extracted value ([5] : [VARCHAR]) - [8592] 
[2023-08-09 10:19:41] [TRACE] [18014] [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.JdbcExtractingLogging.logExtracted(JdbcExtractingLogging.java:28)]: extracted value ([6] : [VARCHAR]) - [F218:C/C]
```

I tried to load the Set Eager with the Ruleset Entity
also with a named Query:
@NamedQuery(name = "Ruleset_by_Species", query = "from Ruleset ruleset join fetch ruleset.rules where ruleset.species.name = :name")

and it is empty(not null) in both cases

thanks for your answers

Heiko

Comment: your child and parent code example are the same.

Comment: How are you sure there are children that belong in the collection? How are you inserting your Rule and Ruleset instances - are you setting both sides of what looks like a bidirectional relationship when you set it up? Does an entityManager.refresh(rulesetInstance) work to load the collection? What is the SQL used to read in the Ruleset and Rule instances, and what data does this return if you execute it on the DB yourself?

Comment: @GuilhermeStella: Sorry - you are right - i changed it.

Comment: Hello - i solved it by changing the rules attribute from Set to List.
Seems to be a bug to me.